# r plot main, iterator in the main option of a R plot

Tags: r, plot, program-entry-point

I need a way to change the main with the iterator "i" of that for, something like main = "Grafico de credibilidad" + i, then when the 6 plots appear their titles change like "Grafico de credibilidad 1" and that 1 increase.

```
momentos1 <- read.table("momentos1.txt")
par(mfrow = c(2,3),bg = "white") 
x<-seq(0,1,0.01) 

for(i in 1:6){
  plot(x,dbeta(x,momentos1$alpha.1.30.[i],momentos1$beta.1.30.[i]),
       main = "Grafico Credibilidad",axes = F,col="blue",
       ylab = "",
       xlab = "",
       ylim = c(0,5),type = "l"
       )
  axis(1,at = seq(0,1,0.1),las=1)
  box()
  grid()
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste()`

```
momentos1 <- read.table("momentos1.txt")
par(mfrow = c(2,3),bg = "white") 
x<-seq(0,1,0.01) 

for(i in 1:6){
  plot(x,dbeta(x,momentos1$alpha.1.30.[i],momentos1$beta.1.30.[i]),
       main = paste("Grafico Credibilidad ",i),axes = F,col="blue",
       ylab = "",
       xlab = "",
       ylim = c(0,5),type = "l"
       )
  axis(1,at = seq(0,1,0.1),las=1)
  box()
  grid()
}
```